# Get-AzWebApp not returning TLS info when looping through multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a script i am running that when i specify a single webapp it will return the TLS info however when I use the script to loop through each webapp in my subscriptions it wont show the tls info. When it works i have added my resource group name and web app name to the Get-AzWebApp cmdlet

```
$arrSubs | ForEach-Object {
        $null = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $_.Id -WarningAction "SilentlyContinue"
        $subscriptionName = $_.Name
        $subscriptionId = $_.SubscriptionId
        $objresources = Get-AzWebApp | Select-Object @{n='SubscriptionName'; e={$subscriptionName}}, 
            @{n='SubscriptionId'; e={$subscriptionId}},
            @{n='ResourceGroupName'; e={$_.ResourceGroupName}},
            @{n='ResourceName'; e={$_.Name}},
            @{n='Kind'; e={$_.Kind}},
            @{n='Location'; e={$_.Location}},
            @{n='tls'; e={$_.SiteConfig | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MinTlsVersion}},
            @{n='HtpsOnly'; e={$_.HttpsOnly}}
        

        if ($null -eq $objresources){
            Write-Output "No Web/Function Apps found in subscirption $subscriptionName"
        }
        elseif (($objresources | Measure-Object).Count -eq 1) {
            [void]$resources.Add($objresources)

            Write-Output "1 Web/Function App found in subscirption $subscriptionName"
        } 
        elseif (($objresources | Measure-Object).Count -gt 1) {
            [void]$resources.AddRange($objresources)

            Write-Output "Multiple Web/Function Apps found in subscirption $subscriptionName"
        }
    Write-Verbose "`t+++ Success `n"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce in my environment and below are my observations:

When you use `Get-AzWebApp` this alone without resource group then i have observered that TLS is blank as below:
[image]

But when I used the below code(with resource group) it worked for me, try to integrate according to your requirement:

```
$webApp=@{}
$e=Get-AzResourceGroup
foreach($x in $e.ResourceGroupName)
{
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $x -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($webApp){
Foreach($y in $webApp){
$a=$y.Name
$b=$y.Kind
$c=$y.Location
$d=$y.SiteConfig.MinTlsVersion
Write-Output "Name :$a"
Write-Output "Kind :$b"
Write-Output "Location :$c"
Write-Output "Resource group name :$x"
Write-Output "Minimum TLS Version :$d"
Write-Output "**********"
Write-Output "**********"
}
}
}
```

[image]